# How to change number corresponding to a key in a dictionary to a symbol

Tags: python, dictionary

draw_histogram({'a': 2, 'b': 7, 'c': 5})

Key:value

prints:

a: --

b: -------

c: -----

How would you change the numbers to "-" and also print in different lines?

Comment: I'm not quite sure of what you're asking. I mean, what's the implementation of `draw_histogram`? I think that in order to do what you're asking `draw_histogram` should be rewritten

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, keep in mind that python dictionaries are not ordered.

```
def draw_histogram(h):
    for k, v in h.items():
        print("%s: %s" % (k, "-" * v))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function to accomplish your task:

```
def histogram(d):
    x=d.keys()
    x.sort()
    for i in x:
        print i+":",d[i]*'-'
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember dictionaries are unordered by default in python.

```
def draw_histogram(d):
    for key, value in d.items():
        print key + ': ' + '-' * value

draw_histogram({'a': 2, 'b': 7, 'c': 5})
```